# Execute IN query in DataStore Google App Engine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

i want to execute `query` which checks data for `IN` criteria on DataStore of app Engine. Is is possible to execute query for `IN` criteria in Datastore? I am using below code for that, but i am not sure whether it will work or not. If its not possible then please suggest any solution for that as i want to check my data against list of criteria.

Code:

```
        EntityManager mgr = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        List<UserFeedMaster> execute = null;

        try {
            mgr = getEntityManager();
            Query query = mgr
                    .createQuery("select f from UserFeedMaster f where f.userName=:userName_fk1 and f.feedBlobKey in (id1,id2,id3)");
            query.setParameter("userName_fk", id);
       } finally {
            mgr.close();
       }

        return CollectionResponse.<UserFeedMaster> builder().setItems(execute)
                .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Engine supports IN queries. The following article explains how to use them:

http://gae-java-persistence.blogspot.com/2009/12/queries-with-and-in-filters.html

Note that there are limitations on IN queries.